# GTA Online refuses to load

Tags: ps3, grand-theft-auto-online

This is an updated and corrected post regarding my “GTA crashing after getting muted” question, which was unfortunately deleted as i had not provided any further details.

Okay, Quite a while back, 2019 i believe, i was playing GTA Online on my PS3, and i managed to get myself in trouble after harassing someone with the use of the in-game message feature. Shortly after said offensive message, i would receive a “message mute”.
All was normal until the game suddenly forces me to a deatmatch, with only 1 other person in it. I was completely clueless about the surprise and so i immediately died right away. Deaths upon deaths later, the match finally ended, with my screen displaying the end-result scoreboard. I wanted to stay no longer in this glitched minigame, so i went to press the usual button to exit. But it didn’t work. More specifically, all the button tooltips below vanished, i’m stuck on loading and my controller ceased to yield any results. I then resorted to my usual; resetting the PS3. I did that, and after going through the usual, i attempt to rejoin GTA Online and it will always crash.

An update about that however:
I’m still trying to fix the problem myself, and it seems that it doesn’t always crash. It will occasionally tell me errors about Rockstar’s servers, much like when GTA Online is currently down. Regardless, it doesn’t let me log in.

Further note in case you didn’t already know, the platform i’m playing on is a Playstation 3.

Please inform me if there’s any missing details, I really want to get this fixed and i don’t want to re-buy GTA V on an entirely different platform which will cost me even more money